# Function acts differently when I call it by M-x and when I call it by load-file/library

Tags: point, save-excursion

I've got this function:

```
(defun move-pointer ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((enable-recursive-minibuffers t))
    (read-string "Go to the main buffer, Move cursor where you like. Come back in the minibuffer, then RETURN: ")
    ))
```

If I evaluate and then call it by `M-x move-pointer` the pointer maintains its last position.

When I save it in a file, this way:

```
(defun move-pointer ()
      (interactive)
      (let ((enable-recursive-minibuffers t))
        (read-string "Go to the main buffer, Move cursor where you like. Come back in the minibuffer, then RETURN: ")
        ))

(move-pointer)
```

and I call it by `M-x load-file` RETURN `myfile.el` the pointer acts as the function was wrapped with `save-excursion`. I mean the pointer revert to its initial position.

1. Why does it happen?
2. How can I keep the pointer position when I call my script?

Comment: it doesn't happen to me. seem to stay at the same point.GNU Emacs 25.3.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.26) of 2018-02-09

Comment: I'm using GNU Emacs 25.3.2 on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: This probably due to the [Window Point](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Point.html).